# How do you make a button increase in size (125%) for few milliseconds and then return it original size on click?

Tags: css, css-transitions

This is probably a css3 transitions thing but I don't know css well enough to create this.  Mainly what I would like to do is make a button grow in size (125% of the original size) for a couple of milliseconds and then revert back to the original size before the page goes to the next page. Is this possible with css/css3/transitions and if so, how would this be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to increase the size for an imperceptible about of time? They may be better way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Grow a button might make alignments problems. You could animate a border color with jQuery, could do cute and simple.

Comment: By "a couple of milliseconds", do you mean a short, but still noticeable, amount of time? Two milliseconds would not be visible to the human eye.

Comment: Yes, I would like it to be noticeable but really fast - a couple of milliseconds.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @persistence - anything under 400ms will probably look to your end user more like a flickery bug than a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your button an `<a>` and use the `:active` pseudo-class to do the expand effect. An easy way to do this without messing up layout is the `outline` property.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### CSS:

```css
.button {
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

.button:active {
    outline: 10px solid black;    
}
```

#### HTML:

```html
<a class="button">press me</a>
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla Developer Network has a great [introduction tutorial on CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).  I recommend stepping through some of the samples and source code to see if that helps you figure out what you're trying to do.

As for timing the length of your animation - you should easily be able to adapt the "transition timing effect sampler" from the link above and try out different timings until you get the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For such a fast effect transitions is not needed, just change the size of the element.

A couple of milliseonds is not enough to make the effect visible. Anything less than 20 ms. is not visible at all, because the screen doesn't update fast enough to show it. Around 100 ms. is needed for it to look like a deliberate effect, and not just a glitch.

Example:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
  var e = $(this);
  e.addClass('grown');
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    e.removeClass('grown');
  }, 100);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/GEHCZ/